# Magento: Bulk 301 redirect from product.html to category/product.html

Tags: magento, redirect, product

Anyone knows how to get bulk 301 redirect from product.html to category/product.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the Settings > Catalog > Searchengine Optimization (german version here, so I hope, the translation is nearly correct). > use category pathes for urls on?

It is not intended in Magento that one product has exactly one category, so the mapping between products and categorys is usually not unique.

Independant from this behaviour you can add rewrite rules to magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules

Catalog > URL Rewrite Management to add rewrites for your desired behaviour. Just add a 301 forwarding as option and everything is fine.

http://thinktank.101interactive.net/magento-programmatically-add-entries-to-url-rewrite-mgmnt-console/